# Animation using xml not working in android

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I created one simple demo project, which does the animation using AnimationDrawable class of android.
Here is my java code:

```
public class TestAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView imgCircleWhite,imgCircleYellow;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imgCircleYellow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCircleYellow);

        animateState(true, imgCircleYellow);

    }

    public void animateState(boolean flag,ImageView imageView)
    {
        imgCircleYellow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_circle_sensor_1);
        AnimationDrawable yourAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground(); 
        if(!flag)
        {   
            //imageView.getAnimation().reset();
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_label_white_1);           
            yourAnimation.stop();           
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_circle_sensor_1); 
            yourAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground(); 
            yourAnimation.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgCircleYellow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_label_yellow_1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my animate_sensor_circle_1.xml, which I've put in drawable folder to use with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_label_white_2"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_label_yellow_1"
        android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

When I run the app, only the first item in the above xml file gets displayed, but animation does not occur repeatedly as it should done.
Can anyone direct me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the right time to call the `AnimationDrawable.start()`. You should do this after the view initialization has been completed. Try this:

```java
final ImageView imgCircleYellow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCircleYellow);
imgCircleYellow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_circle_sensor_1);
imgCircleYellow.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        animateState(true, imgCircleYellow);
    }
```

Check this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490922/813135

Comment: This is weired. Your solution worked. But how its possible that my view has not been initialized properly? Because I am calling the `.start()` method after setting its backgroundResource to my animation-drawable resource?? Can you explain me in more detail? Also I want this animation on about six images. So Do I have to declare all them as final and then animate? Your solution worked but  still not the elegant. Please suggest me how can I achieve the same on all images in my activity.. Thanks

Comment: I did not mean to make an elegant solution, just the general idea. The problem with your approach is that during Activity.onCreate(), nothing is actually displayed on the screen yet because views haven't completed initializing.
In order to start playing the animation immediately after the activity is displayed, try calling the `AnimationDrawable.start()` in the `Activity.onWindowFocusChanged()`. There is a very good explanation in Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start%28%29

Comment: Great! I agree as per the document says in the above posted link. But even I tried to make it work in the `onClick` of a Button. Then also it didn't work. What can be the issue?

Comment: I cannot answer this question without seeing the code. It depends on where and how the `View.OnClickListener` was created and assigned to the button. Maybe someone else might have the answer.