# I have a loader animation but , sometimes it doesn't start the animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, loading, android-drawable

I have this ImageView that I use as a loader:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loader_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/loader_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/loader_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/loader_bottom_offset"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

I have a static method in my Utils class that does this:

```
public static void setLoaderVisible(ImageView loader){

    loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
    loader.bringToFront();
    AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) loader.getBackground();
    anim.setOneShot(false);
    anim.start();
}
```

I noticed that in some parts the loader does show the animation, going through the drawables, but sometimes it only shows the first picture. Why doesn't it want to animate all the time?
This is my animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus4" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

EDIT: I did try using a post, like this:

```
public static void setLoaderVisible(ImageView loader)
{ 
loader.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
loader.bringToFront();

final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) loader.getDrawable();
loader.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        anim.start();
    } 
}); 
}
```

And also tried to use a AnimatedImageView class found here: [AnimationDrawable not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490803/animationdrawable-not-playing)
but still the same issue.

I noticed that the animation works in almost all my classes. I have a activity that contains fragment and in there the loader does not animate. Tried putting the loader inside the fragment, and inside the activity, but the results are the same. Any ideeas?

Answer (score 1):

try following method if it works,

```
public static void setLoaderVisible(ImageView loader)
{
    loader.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
    loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loader.bringToFront();

    final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) loader.getDrawable();
    loader.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            anim.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: tried it, and still the same issue, found on another post a modified ImageView called AnimatedImageView and am trying with that one now, but the issue persists. Might be because the app is doing to much on the main thread?